# Parse/deserialising newtonsoft.json in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, parse-platform, json.net

I am pretty new to `vb.net` and to `json` I am using `newtonsoft` to parse my `json` responses but am struggling with this `json`

https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/MotHistory?licencePlate=mt09nks&apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount

I can load the main parts date, mileage etc into `listview` OK 
But I want to be able to click on a row and the load the advisory's and failures (if any) into `listboxes` to be viewed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean *parse*?  It would be easier to deserialize it and have all the info in a class or list of class objects.  No need to parse bit by bit.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: add appropriate tag